# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, load Imageview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, nestedscrollview

Update Question
I like RecyclerView using Glide, because image will be load when item has appeared in the screen.
Example : 100 item, 10 item has appeared in the screen, glide just load 10 item.

But when RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, image will be load together (100 item load together).
Question : how to use glide with RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Java Code

```
    NestedScrollView nestedScroll = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScroll);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linear = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linear);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: obvioulsy because `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` which basiacally means "takes as same height as sum of height of all items" (which also makes RecyclerView unscrollable - only NestedScrollView is scrolling)

Comment: What you had done to load images?

Comment: @PratikButani seems like you don't understand what is going on ... the problem is that all images loads at the same time ... because he made LinearLayout with from his RecyclerView

Comment: @Selvin then why you give him to suggestion of layout. I dont think its correct answer.

Comment: [This is what happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lor6H.png) red is NestedScrollView/Screen, black RecyclerView, blue RecyclerView items

Comment: @Selvin can you give me code how to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?
i know you mean, Glide load all image because RecyclerView not detected scrolling

Comment: @PratikButani yes, i had done to load image

Comment: What for? What you wana achive?

Comment: Why down vote? Where is the mistake?

Comment: @TomtomDeCrab have you used priority?

Comment: @Selvin no, solution load image as list inside NestedScrollView and Glide?

Comment: as I wrote in first comment solution is set `android:layout_height` to something **opposite to** `wrap_content` ... but question is what for you wana put RecyclerView into NestedScrollView

Comment: @Selvin i has try change wrap_content in NestedScrollView but still load all image together

Comment: I meant **do not use wrap_content** not *use it in NestedScrollView*

Comment: @Selvin you mean set height manually?

Answer (score -1):

Glide supports your wished behavior with the **Priority** enum and the `.priority()` method.

The enum gives you four different options. This is the list ordered with increasing priority:

> - Priority.LOW
> - Priority.NORMAL
> - Priority.HIGH
> - Priority.IMMEDIATE

Usage Example:

```
Glide.with( context )
        .load( "url" )
        .priority( Priority.HIGH )
        .into( imageViewHero );
```

Tryout it. Hope it will useful to you.

Source: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-request-priorities

Comment: Thank you, but image sill load together

Comment: @TomtomDeCrab https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1075#issuecomment-199349653

Comment: Thank you, it is the problem, Glide will not work perfect when RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, maybe Glide read all item in RecyclerView has visible in screen, so all image load together